# LINQ to SQL: Composite FK only half nullable

Tags: linq-to-sql, composite-key, sqlmetal

In a multitenant application that uses composite keys
(e.g. `SiteId, $(Table)Id`)
for everything, I have the following two tables:

```
Owner (
     SiteId bigint NOT NULL,
     OwnerId bigint NOT NULL,
     ThingId bigint NULL
)

Thing (
     SiteId bigint NOT NULL,
     ThingId bigint NOT NULL
)
```

and a foreign key from `Owner (SiteId, ThingId)` to `Thing (SiteId, ThingId)`.

If I write a method like this:

```
void RemoveThing(Owner owner)
{
    owner.Thing = null;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I get the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a
Thing and a Owner. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (Owner.MultiId,
Owner.ThingId) cannot be set to null.
at System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.SynchDependentData()
at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ValidateAll(IEnumerable`1 list)
at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
at proj.Program.RemoveThing() in C:\proj\Program.cs:line 115
```

To fix this, I could add a second copy of `SiteId` (perhaps `ThingSiteId`) to the `Owner` table. But it's only ever going to be equal to the SiteId, so I'd be spending database size and schema complexity to work around my ORM.

How can I tell LINQ to SQL that it doesn't need to worry about that half of the foreign key relationship, and only set `Owner.ThingId=NULL`?

Comment: I can't answer the question directly, but I think it is worth considering just bypassing linq2sql for this one operation and using something like SqlCommand.

Comment: What's the primary key on your owner and thing tables?

Comment: The PK on Owner is `SiteId, OwnerId`, and on Thing is `SiteId, ThingId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `ThingId = null` instead of `Thing = null`. Don't reuse your `DataContext`, otherwise you might get a "Foreign key is already set" exception.

---

*LINQ is actively preventing this from being any easier. In `ChangeTracker.SynchDependentData()`, every column is checked to see if it is part of any associations, and then an exception is thrown if the column was*

1. *set to null*
2. *the association has ANY non-nullable columns(!)*

*This is a bug in LINQ-to-SQL, in my opinion.*